# How to use between and where condition together in Spring Data Mongo DB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document called Employee. I want to query all the employees whose designation is "Developer" and joiningDate between 2019 and 2020.

```
class Employee{
    private String name;
    private String designation;
    private Date joiningDate;
}

**// i want where condition on designation to be included in the following** 
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, String> {
    @Query("{'joiningDate' : {$gte : ?0, $lte : ?1}}")
    public List<Employee> findByJoiningDateBetween(LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime endTime);
}
```

Comment: are you using JPA ? Why extends `MongoRepository`?

Comment: @KenChan Yes. I need to i have already between condition. now i wants to add where condition on another column

Comment: then why extend `MongoRepository` ? JPA is used with RDBMS which is the totally different from MongoDB......

Comment: @KenChan I'm sorry. It's Mongo DB not JPA. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Really, this is not JPA, this is Spring Data MongoDB.

This is not a Document, the Document must be annotated as @Document and have @Id (String or better ObjectId).

If you want to use a complex query, maybe the better way to use own repository method implementation:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends MongoRepository<Employee, String>, EmployeeRepositoryBase {
}
```

---

```
public interface EmployeeRepositoryBase {
    List<Employee> findByJoiningDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeRepositoryImpl implements EmployeeRepositoryBase {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public List<Employee> findJoiningDateBetween(final Date startDate, final Date endDate) {
        final var query = Query.query(Criteria.where("...").is(...).and("...").gte(...).lte(...);
        return mongoTemplate(query, Employee.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its Mongo DB only not JPA.

Answer (score 1):

In your repository use this way

```
List<Employee> findByJoiningDateBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

[refer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)